# appending string- works with string with one word but not two

Tags: objective-c, url

I'm appending a string to a url which then inputs into a database, it works with a single worded string e.g

```
NSString * string = @"one";
```

however if my string has two words such as

```
NSString * string = @"one two";
```

it does not work. Please see the code below.

```
NSMutableString * urlString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:url];

[urlString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@",kWord,word]];
```

The problem obviously lies with stringWithFormat;

turns out the problem is with the space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Space characters (and certain others) are not allowed in URLs. You need to convert the space to `%20`. Here is the proper solution:

```
NSString *url = @"http://example.com/process.php";
NSString *kword = @"param";
NSString *word = @"one two";
NSMutableString * urlString = [url mutableCopy];
[urlString appendFormat:@"?%@=%@", kWord, [word stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: thanks, can you tell me what is happening with the last two lines? I fairly new

Comment: Have you read the docs for `mutableCopy` and `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`?

Comment: thanks @rmaddy is works perfectly, exactly what I was looking, had not come across this before.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried couple exampes here, hope it helps.

```
NSString *string1 = @"String1";
NSString *string2 = @"String2 String3";

NSMutableString *appendingString=[NSMutableString stringWithString: [string1 stringByAppendingString:string2]];
NSLog(@"String1:%@  String2:%@",string1,string2);
NSLog(@"StringwithAppend:%@",appendingString);

//------
NSString *url=@"www.abc.com";
NSMutableString * urlString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:url];
NSLog(@"URL String before append:%@",urlString);
NSString *kWord=@"key";
NSString *word=@"word";
[urlString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@",kWord,word]];
NSLog(@"URL String after append:%@",urlString);
```

Console Log:

String1:String1  String2:String2 String3
StringwithAppend:String1String2 String3
URL String before append:www.abc.com
URL String after append:www.abc.com?key=word

Comment: Thanks kingv that was helpful however the problem is that it wont insert into the database when the word string has two words in it e.g word = @"word one";

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way.

NSString * urlString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@=%@", url, kword, word];

Comment: does not work...it works the original way with one string like I said above